# Hide / Show Dynamically Generated input box with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form, containing a select dropdown, and an input box.
The input box should be hidden unless "Other" option is selected from the dropdown.

My problem is that there is a button, that clones this code, and create additional copies.

I don't know how to manage in JS to show only the input box related to the select dropdown, as i can't number them it's not static. It can be even 10 or just 1.

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select name="diet[]" class="form-control diet"> 
            <option value="None">Dietary Requirements</option>
            <option >None</option>
            <option >Vegetarian</option>
            <option >Gluten Free</option>
            <option >Lactose Free</option>
            <option >Kosher</option>
            <option value="other">Other (specify below)</option>
        </select>
        <input  type="text" name="otherdiet[]" class="form-control diet" placeholder="Please Specify here" style="margin-right:0;">
    </div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select name="diet[]" class="form-control diet"> 
        <option value="None">Dietary Requirements</option>
        <option >None</option>
        <option >Vegetarian</option>
        <option >Gluten Free</option>
        <option >Lactose Free</option>
        <option >Kosher</option>
        <option value="other">Other (specify below)</option>
    </select>
    <input  type="text" name="otherdiet[]" class="form-control diet" placeholder="Please Specify here" style="margin-right:0;">
</div>
```

Comment: Well, to start off, how would you do it for 1 dropdown, not dynamically created? You can start from there and tell us what you have so we can help you complete it.

Comment: I would do a style="display:block" on the input, and put an onClick on the select which calls js, and in js set display to block by elementID

Comment: Yes that's the problem. The newly created ones.

Comment: @blex oops forgot that, good point - deleted offending comment

Comment: This is the JS creating the new ones:

 function addGuest() {
 var id = makeid()
 var fieldset = $('.guest-fieldset:first').clone().appendTo('#guest-fieldset-container');
 fieldset.attr('id', id);
 var guest = fieldset.find('input.guest-name');
 guest.val('');
 var attending = fieldset.find('select.attending');
 attending.after("<span class='remove-guest' data-icon='&#xe051;' onclick='delGuest(\"" + id + "\");'></span>");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start of by binding an onChange event handler to the select fields. Then check whether the 'other' option was selected or something else. If the 'other' option was selected, add the input to the parent element. If a different option was selected, then see if the input is there, and remove it if it is.

```
jQuery('form').on('change', 'select.form-control', function() {
    if (this.value == 'other') {

        // In here you could check for a certain class on the select button
        // e.g. if (jQuery(this).hasClass('diet'))

        var input = jQuery("<input>")
            .attr("type", "text")
            .attr('name', 'otherdiet[]')
            .attr('placeholder', 'Please specify here')
            .addClass('form-control diet');

        jQuery(this).parent().append(input);
    }
    else {
        var input = jQuery(this).parent().find('input[name="otherdiet[]"]');

        if (input.length > 0)
            input.remove();
    }
});
```

Now if you have multiple of these dropdowns, where you want to do something sligtly different for each one, you could add a class, id, or any other kind of distinguishable attribute to the select element. Then in the jQuery code, check for that distinguishable attribute and perform an appropriate action.

Comment: Thanks, i have pasted to code into my js file, but nothing happens when i select the 'other' option.

It should show up isn't it? 

This is the live site:
http://thewedsiteof.com/natandryan/#rsvp

Comment: Changed `form-control select` to `.form-control select`, try that.
Als note that you can use console.log() to debug your code and see what works and what doesn't. Press F12 to open the console and see the messages you logged and any errors that ocurred while running the code.

Comment: @ThijsRiezebeek still nothing.Also console is empty on click no errors

Comment: @blex i removed beacuse the js should create it isn't it? now i put it back but can't see the point

Comment: Can you add `console.log(this.value);` before the line `if (this.value == 'other') {` to see if the value is picked up correctly.

Comment: Added and console is still empty @Thijs Riezebeek

Comment: I put it to beginning of function, Now it shows undefined.

Comment: I think I messed up the selector. Try changing `.form-control select` to `select.form-control`. I thought the select was within an element with class `form-control`, but is the select element itself that has the `form-control` class.

Comment: Cool now it did something but created 3 then 4 then 5 input fields.
Should only create one. Can you have a look please?
http://thewedsiteof.com/natandryan/#rsvp

Comment: every time i click on "other" it adds one more input box. if i click 5 times on "other " there will be 5 boxes underneath.

Comment: I see the problem. I do not understand why that is happening though. Also  you should remove the showBox() function and just put the jQuery code I provided in a jquery(document).ready() scope.

Comment: Works fine now. removed it.